# Paypal IPN Payment_Status sometimes null

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

In my listener method for Paypal Instant Payment Notification I very occasionally receive a null valued payment_status.  This is supposed to be set to a string value like "completed", "pending", "refunded" etc.  Neither do I subsequently get a completed status sent in any follow up IPN; as a result, I don't do any server side processing and the users can't access their purchased items.

Perhaps I should return a BadRequest and the IPN will get sent again?

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What is the transaction type? Not all transactions have payments: for example, subscription EOT or cancellation. Sending Bad Request isn't likely to change anything.

Comment: The many code samples I've based my listener on all seem to suggest that I can expect a payment_status.  This is just a simple express checkout . I've added some logging to get the transaction type....

Comment: You should refer the associated transactions to PayPal support.